# How to write html code inside a php file

Tags: php, html

I want to write an html form inside my login.php and submit it in login.php itself .So how can I  write html inside this php file?If I write  tag it shows error.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to, first, name your file with the following extension: `.php` so the code can be parsed by the server.
Then, put your PHP code that processes the form before your `HTML` code.
Write your `HTML` form.

Finally, if you want the PHP code to be executed if, and only if, the form is submitted, process as follow:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)) // which is the same as doing if($_POST); be sure not to use isset() function as $_POST variable is always set
{
    // do the form processing
}
?>
<html>
    <!-- your HTML markup -->
    <form action="" method="post"> <!-- << leave action attribute blank to submit the form to the very same page -->
        <!-- your form -->
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// php code here
?>

html code here

<?php
// more php code here
?>

more html code here
```

if you plan to use php code anywhere in the file, use the .php file extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bar = <<<EOS
  <div class="container"><h1>Hello World</h1><div>
EOS;
```

Sometimes this method of assigning html string to a variable is very useful